# Why calling StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx requires .NET Fx 3.5 to be installed?

Tags: .net, .net-4.8

On a Windows 10 or 11 machine where .NET 3.5 is not installed, calling `StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx()` require Windows to ask the user to install .NET 3.5, why? is it possible to circumvent this dialog? or test if .NET 3.5 is not installed?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Program {

   [DllImport("mscoree.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx")]
   private static extern bool StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(string wszFilePath,
                          byte fForceVerification,
                          ref byte pfWasVerified);
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      byte wasVerified = Convert.ToByte(false);
      byte forceVerification = Convert.ToByte(true);
      var bChecked = StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(
         @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Collections.dll",
                       forceVerification,
                       ref wasVerified);
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11690) it looks like not much can be done except removing the call to `StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx()`.

> Strong names are deprecated in .NET Core. There are no APIs for strong
> name verification in .NET Core and the runtime does not ever verifies
> strong names either.